# HOW CAN I FIX THIS ERROR IN NS2?

Tags: ns2

While running my tcl script for new protocol in ns2 it shows error as:

> num_nodes is set 108
>    > invalid command name “Agent/HEBM”
>         while executing “Agent/HEBM set radius_2” (file  “balance.tcl” line31)

Comment: while running my tcl script for new protocol  in ns2 it shows error as:

num_nodes is set 108                                    
  invalid command name “Agent/HEBM”
      while executing
“Agent/HEBM set radius_2”
(file  “balance.tcl” line31)


please, reply as soon as possible, it will be very helpful to implement my project.

Comment: »»  invalid command name “Agent/HEBM” «« : You are using a (wrong) copy of an executable `ns` with no "Agent/HEBM". ( HEBM is an unknown ns2 term.) https://drive.google.com/file/d/1FCjn-9fkR7tKeqClUpHsleaEdnoKRZzq/view?usp=sharing

Comment: If you want an answer : Please edit your question → What is HEBM, and where did you get the script. And most important: Show the code. `balance.tcl` is an unknown file.

Comment: num_nodes is set 108   
  invalid command name “Agent/HEBM”
      while executing
“Agent/HEBM set radius_2”

(file  “balance.tcl” line31)